# Error : ImportError: cannot import name 'getuid' from 'os' (C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\os.py) how to fix os dont have getuid

Tags: python

Error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'getuid' from 'os' (C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\os.py)`
mine os is Windows 10
the script is :
https://gofile.io/d/R2QQpr

Comment: Paste your code here. Don't share the file like this, we don't want to download it

Comment: Also that's normal https://github.com/Parsely/streamparse/issues/415

Comment: can i do it with pastebin? cus it bugged somehow when i tried to inserter it in